# how to optimize mysql queries contains "in" operand?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like

```
select * from logs where uid in (id1, id2, ...)
```

but I worry about the performance if there's very many ids in the list of in(), like say over 2000 ids, even according output of explain, this statement does use index on uid column.
I want to know if there's other way to query it with this kind of conditions, or how to do some optimize for this sql statement?

any answer is appreciated.

supplement: the table format is myisam, and for some reason, I can't change the storage engine.

Comment: Are you having problems with this?

Comment: if the ids in () comes from another table on certain conditions, you can use join. if uid comes from arbitrary user inputs, I don't think you can do much about it

Comment: @andreas yes, the ids come from another data source. does it help if I separate them into "uid=id1 or uid=id2 or ...."?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  not yet, I'm going to make a test for that situation with 2000 ids.

Answer (score 2):

2000 items?!?  Whoa!

SUGGESTION:
Write your 2000 items to a table, and do an inner join instead of "where uid in (...)"

Comment: Is it substantially different?

Comment: these uids vary for each request, would inserting into a temp table cost much?

Answer (score 0):

I already mentioned a link to a similar question in a comment above.

Besides, the queries of the kind are supposed to be intensively used in MySQL to speed up some kinds of JOINS. The result of the query can easily be cached by the query cache, thus speeding up a repetitive join on your site (that is when you split a join into several smaller queries, where the cached result of one of them is constantly invalidated, but the other is rather stable). The `IN` operator sorts the operands to reduce random index reads.

The only thing you should really care of, is to pass ints as ints instead of strings, so that the operands would be sorted correctly.